# How to speed up 'intersection' tool for big amount of data?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, intersection

I can't figure out how to work with a large dataset. The problem is: I want to know how many points (over 700 000 adresses) are within a polygon layer (it's made out of 5 layers, train noise)(they are both shapefiles). Using the 'Join by location' tool or 'Add polygon attributes to point' (SAGA) would take days to calculate it. I tried using a Spatial lite database and a Postgis database (SQL) but that also took way too long (10 attributes took over a minute to calculate). This is the script I used:

```
SELECT
bag_panden."id", trein_geluid_nacht."fromto"
FROM
bag_panden
inner JOIN
trein_geluid_nacht
ON ST_Within(bag_panden.geom, trein_geluid_nacht.geom)
where
bag_panden."id" <= 100
```

If anyone knows a way to calculate this faster I would like to know how. Maybe a different tool? Some Settings? A different script?

I am using QGIS 2.18.14

Comment: Isn't there some sort of select by location and then find the count of selected features? That's how I would do this in QGIS or ArcGIS (or OGR), it's less intensive than a clip or spatial join.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you for your answer. I'm running the 'select by location' right now, but it's stuck at 0% for about ten minutes... (It seems to be working in the task manager) I'm afraid this would also take a lot of time

Comment: Could you create subsets of either you polygon or your point data?

Comment: Is there a spatial index? Are both the selecting geometry and the query geometries in the same spatial reference?

Comment: @Erik That's a good suggestion and that would be my last resort if I couldn't find an answer here. But first of all that would probably take as much time as one big dataset and second of all it would take some time to join the datasets back together. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @MichaelStimson Yes, there is a spatial index and they are both in the same spatial reference

Comment: you are mixing softwares; QGIS and PostGIS *are* working well hand in hand, but refering to QGIS tools while presenting PostGIS specific SQL makes this question somewhat misleading. please edit the title/tags according to your question body, and/or decide upon the tool/software you want...you can always ask a second question for other tools.

Comment: could you also specify: it's *one* number you're after, i.e. the total count of points intersecting the polygon layer? since you seem to try to recieve an attribute for each layer?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I found the answer! I've downloaded the newest QGIS (3.2.3), applied 'Fix geometries' and then applied 'Join attributes by location'. It joined the point layer and the polygon layer. As result it gave me the point layer with the data of the polygon (when overlapping or else empty). It took about 45 minutes. Thanks for the help!